# ManyToOne mapping not working when inside an Embeddable class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project with Spring Boot (2.2.6.RELEASE) and JPA, and I am facing an issue that is bringing me nightmares...

I have a weak entity whose PK is a composite key of primary keys from parent tables.

```
    +-----------------+
    |       BAR       |
    +-----------------+
    | BAR_ID PK       |
    | NAME            |
    +-----------------+
            |
            |       +-----------------+
            |       |       FOO       |
            +------<+-----------------+
            +------<| BAR_ID PK FK    |
            |       | BAZ_ID PK FK    |
            |       +-----------------+
            |
    +-----------------+
    |       BAZ       |
    +-----------------+
    | BAZ_ID PK       |
    | NAME            |
    +-----------------+
```

So I have the following mapping...

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "FOO")
    public class Foo implements Serializable {

        @Data
        @Embeddable
        public static class ID implements Serializable {
            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID")
            private Bar bar;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="BAZ_ID")
            private Baz baz;
        }

        @EmbeddedId
        private ID id;
    }


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BAR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_BAR", sequenceName = "SEQ_BAR")
    public class Bar implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_BAR")
        @Column(name = "BAR_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "BAZ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_BAZ", sequenceName = "SEQ_BAZ")
    public class Baz implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_BAZ")
        @Column(name = "BAZ_ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

    }
```

and the following Repository interface:

```
    @Repository
    public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Foo.ID> {

    }
```

then I try doing findById

```
    fooRepository.findById(new Foo.ID(new Bar(1), new Baz(1));
```

and got the problem:

When I call fooRepository.findById(), although the row is fetched from database, ManyToOne mappings for Bar e Baz are not working properly. That means, whether I do `foo.getId().getBar().getName()` or `foo.getId().getBaz().getName()`, attribute `name` is null for both Bar and Baz objects (of course, the atrributes are not null in the database).

So my questions are:

This should work, right?
What am I doing wrong?
I have already tried changing fetch type to EAGER, but that didn't work at all.

I really appreciate any replies.

Comment: I have found a way to solve this by using IdClass instead of EmbeddedId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I print database execution statement,the statement is `Hibernate: select foo0_.bar_id as bar_id2_2_0_, foo0_.baz_id as baz_id1_2_0_ from foo foo0_ where foo0_.bar_id=? and foo0_.baz_id=?`.Obviously the JPA does not query the Bar and Baz tables,so `foo.getBar().getName()` certainly will be null.

You can use follow way to achieve the same effect.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@Data
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BAR_ID")
    private Bar bar;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BAZ_ID")
    private Baz baz;

}

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    Foo findByBarAndBaz(Bar bar, Baz baz);
}
```

use it like this:

```
Foo byId = fooRepository.findByBarAndBaz(new Bar(1L), new Baz(1L));
Bar bar = byId.getBar();
System.out.println(bar.toString());
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. But, as far as I know, JPA should lazily fetch getId().getBar(), shouldn't it?

Comment: Not totally,it depends on what you are using `@OneToMany` or other annotations.

Comment: You mean I have to map `@OneToMany` on Bar and Baz to Foo to make it work?

Comment: I modified my answer,maybe you can try the above way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. However, I have done this using `IdClass` instead, and it's working fine. I found this a little bit verbose, but works for me.